# What is debugging specifically?

Tags: debugging

What is debugging a code and how would I go about this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Debugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging) is the process to in which you make sure your code contains no [bugs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_bug) (or at least as few as possible ;) ).

And there is no "way to go about this" per se. But there are widely accepted techniques that are time-proven to work (as you will see in the first link).

There are also specialized tools for when in the need to debug some specific peace of code... but that will always depend on your needs.

Comment: @Michael Thank you on the correction :). But I'm interested (for real) to know why did you delete the 'or at least as few as possible' part.

Comment: because our edits stepped over each other, and the SO revision view doesn't accurately track every change, so exactly what happened isn't always clear. Please modify as needed; I'll keep away. :-)

Comment: Oh! No problem... I just thought that was you ^^

Answer (score 0):

Debugging code is observing it's run-time behavior, typically through a rich IDE such as Eclipse or Visual Studio. You can inspect the values assigned to variables and set breakpoints in the code where you are basically saying that you would like to start observing the programs behavior when that line of code is executed.